# Symfony 3: Array to string conversion error when passing object/multidimensional array into ChoiceType form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, object, multidimensional-array

I'm in the process of upgrading from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4, and having to update how my forms work accordingly.

After looking through tons of similar questions and answers, as well as the Symfony docs, I can't seem seem to find a working solution. No matter what I try, I keep running into this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

I've tried adding the 'multiple' => true form option (even though I don't want multiple options to be selectable - I just want the form & drop down list to at least load for starters at this point), and have also tried using a DataTransformer (though possibly set up incorrectly). But, like I said, I always seem to get this error no matter how I configure it.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation: where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

Thus, you have to change it to a one dimensional array of `'label' => value`